# OpenLayers. Identifying overlapping Overlays

Tags: openlayers

I have a map with many Overlays using OpenLayers 8.0. Users can select any Overlay and drag it to a new position.

Once the map is rendered I'd like to check if any overlays overlap any others and make the necessary adjustments.

The OpenLayers API has `getPosition()` to get a map-based position of a single point within an Overlay and `getElement()` to give access to the `HTMLElement` attributes (such as the bounding rectangle).

I can't find an API to get all four corners of an Overlay to check for an overlap with other overlays. I can convert the result of `getPosition()` to a lon/lat, for example, but I can't get any other coordinate of the Overlay.

Q1. has anyone done this in practice?

Q2. should I have used `Overlay` to display multiple labels that the user can drag around the map or a Feature?